# EKS Nodes not registering to the cluster when using terraform

Tags: terraform, amazon-eks, terraform-modules

first i create a VPC with this configuration, this is stored as module in github. I am pretty new with terraform and EKS any help would be appricated.

again i am including codes from several diffrent file, and vpc portion is module in github.

main.tf

```
data "aws_availability_zones" "az_available" {
  state = "available"
  filter {
    name   = "zone-name"
    values = var.desired-azs
  }

}

locals {
  azs = slice(data.aws_availability_zones.az_available.names, 0, var.desired-subnets)
}

module "vpc" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"
  version = "3.18.1"

  name = "${var.la-env}"
  cidr = var.la-cider

  azs              = local.azs
  private_subnets  = [for k, v in local.azs : cidrsubnet(var.la-cider, 8, k)]
  public_subnets   = [for k, v in local.azs : cidrsubnet(var.la-cider, 8, k + 50)]
  database_subnets = [for k, v in local.azs : cidrsubnet(var.la-cider, 8, k + 100)]

  enable_nat_gateway           = true
  enable_vpn_gateway           = false
  create_database_subnet_group = true
  enable_dns_hostnames = true
  enable_dns_support = true


  tags = merge(
    var.la-tags,
    {
      Terraform   = "true"
      Environment = var.la-env
      Owner       = var.owner
    },
  )
}
```

variables.tf

```
variable "region" {
  type        = string
  description = "the region to deploy into"
  default     = "us-east-1"
}

variable "ea-env" {
  type        = string
  description = "The environment name (STAGE/PROD/PREPROD/ect)"
}

variable "ea-cider" {
  type        = string
  description = "The ip cider block to use"
}

variable "owner" {
  type        = string
  description = "the Owner/deployer email address"
}

variable "ea-tags" {
  type        = map(string)
  description = "Custom Tags to add"
  default     = {}
}

variable "desired-azs" {
  type        = list(string)
  description = "list of desired azs"
  default     = ["*"]
}

variable "desired-subnets" {
  type        = number
  description = "the number of subnets to create"
  default     = 3
}
```

output.tf

```
output "vpc-id" {
  value = module.vpc.vpc_id
}

output "database-subnet" {
  value = module.vpc.database_subnets
}

output "private-subnet" {
  value = module.vpc.private_subnets
}

output "public-subnet" {
  value = module.vpc.public_subnets
}
```

again all the one above is stored as module in github, which is in private repo. So using that vpc, I am trying to build a EKS with terraform. Which i will include the code to below.

main.tf

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-west-2"
}

module "eks" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws"
  version = "~> 19.0"

  cluster_name    = var.la-env
  cluster_version = "1.24"

  cluster_endpoint_public_access  = true

  cluster_addons = {
    coredns = {
      most_recent = true
    }
    kube-proxy = {
      most_recent = true
    }
    vpc-cni = {
      most_recent = true
    }
  }

  vpc_id                   = module.vpc.vpc-id
  subnet_ids               = module.vpc.public-subnet
  control_plane_subnet_ids = module.vpc.public-subnet


  # Self Managed Node Group(s)
  self_managed_node_group_defaults = {
    instance_type                          = "t3.micro"
    update_launch_template_default_version = true
    iam_role_additional_policies = {
      AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore"
    }
  }

  self_managed_node_groups = {
    one = {
      name         = "eks_self_managed"
      max_size     = 2
      desired_size = 1

      use_mixed_instances_policy = true
      mixed_instances_policy = {
        instances_distribution = {
          on_demand_base_capacity                  = 0
          on_demand_percentage_above_base_capacity = 10
          spot_allocation_strategy                 = "capacity-optimized"
        }

        override = [
          {
            instance_type     = "t3.micro"
            weighted_capacity = "1"
          },
          {
            instance_type     = "t3.large"
            weighted_capacity = "2"
          },
        ]
      }
    }
  }
  
  tags = merge(
    var.la-tags,
    {
      Terraform   = "true"
      Environment = var.la-env
      Owner       = var.owner
    },
  )
}
```

vpc.tf

```
module "vpc" {
  source  = "git::https://github.com/uttambaral/infrastructure-modules.git//network/vpc?ref=VPC_MODIFICATION"

  la-env = var.la-env
  la-cider = "10.0.0.0/16"
  owner = ""
}
```

variables.tf

```
variable "region" {
  type        = string
  description = "the region to deploy into"
  default     = "us-east-1"
}

variable "la-env" {
  type        = string
  description = "The environment name (STAGE/PROD/PREPROD/ect)"
}

variable "la-cider" {
  type        = string
  description = "The ip cider block to use"
}

variable "owner" {
  type        = string
  description = "the Owner/deployer email address"
}

variable "la-tags" {
  type        = map(string)
  description = "Custom Tags to add"
  default     = {}
}

variable "desired-azs" {
  type        = list(string)
  description = "list of desired azs"
  default     = ["*"]
}

variable "desired-subnets" {
  type        = number
  description = "the number of subnets to create"
  default     = 3
}
```

remote.tf

```
terraform {
   backend "s3" {
      bucket = "la-infrastructure-live-terraform-state"
      key = "example/dev/us-west-2/eks"
      region = "us-east-1"
   }
}
```

I've tried what I can from my side, spent hours trying to figure this thing out.

everything will get built perfectly fine, but when i go to the aws console and look at the registered nodes i see nothing there, and i don't get any error from terraform as well.

Comment: Why do you have two VPC modules?

Answer (score 0):

**1st issue I've fould was in /etc/eks/bootstrap.sh.**
in my case `kubelete` version was `1.26.3` and it return false case when compare it with hardcoded `1.26.0` in the script.

https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-eks-ami/blob/master/files/bootstrap.sh#L478

this line cause wrong `--cloud-provider` key in the systemd unit and it can not register the node on the EKS.

This "fix" in userdata resolve the issues for me (make sure you run this BEFORE the bootstrup.sh execution. The Terrafrom module allows to place you userdata before and afret the bootstrap):

```
sed -i 's|KUBELET_CLOUD_PROVIDER="external"|KUBELET_CLOUD_PROVIDER="aws"|g' /etc/eks/bootstrap.sh
```

**2nd possible issue might be missed `aws-auth` configmap in the `kube-system`**
Create it if not exist or edit to make sure the node's IAM role has permissions to register itself

```
kubectl get cm aws-auth -n kube-system -o yaml
```

there should be somthing like this.

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  mapAccounts: |
    []
  mapRoles: |
    - "groups":
      - "system:bootstrappers"
      - "system:nodes"
      "rolearn": "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/the-role-attached-to-the-instance-profile"
      "username": "system:node:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}"
    - "groups":
      - "system:masters"
      "rolearn": "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/my-admin-user-role-name"
      "username": "my-admin-user"
  mapUsers: |
    []
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Terraform
    terraform.io/module: terraform-aws-modules.eks.aws
  name: aws-auth
  namespace: kube-system
```